# Where can I find a Word document in a language other than English?

Tags: ms-word

This might sound a bit strange, but does anyone know where can I find a Microsoft Word document (if possible, in a format compatible with the 2007/2010 versions) in a language as different as possible from English (for example, Chinese or some Arab language)?
I need this to test an add-in I wrote for Word. The document should be a real-world text document, not just a few words written just for fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an advanced google search using language = "Chinese" and filetype = "doc"

Comment: [Click here to run the suggested search](http://www.google.com/search?q=filetype:doc&hl=en&lr=lang_zh-TW)